# Google Wave Robot - Change to Wave in response to an external event

Tags: google-wave

I am writing a Google Wave Robot that allows users to "manage a wave". I plan to have a configuration page on my website. When the configuration is changed, ideally all waves where this user added by this user should change immediately (or at least next time someone views the wave). What is the best way of doing this?

Apparently, "a robot cannot contact Wave directly; it can only respond to wave-related events and cron events". If I decide to go the cron route, how quickly can I update the Wave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out the [new Robot API v2](http://googlewavedev.blogspot.com/2010/03/introducing-robots-api-v2-rise-of.html) - it enables robots to actively push information into Wave.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, cron does not work at the moment (2009-11-28) either. You could add a gadget, that changes its internal state - for example 1 sec after wave loaded using a timer - and listen for DOCUMENT_CHANGED or BLIP_SUBMITTED (less volume) events. But unless your bot comes with a gadget anyway, this is of course not very pretty.

=HC